# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' while writing 400.000 records to file

Tags: c#

I really REALLY hope that someone could help me.

I have to pass almost 400.000 records from a database to a textfile
Because of this amount the extension of the textfile is just something
I made up ...(.you_name_it)
I get an error while writing the data to the file at +/- 9000 records.
The error = Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown
And I don't know the solution :(

This is the peace of code I use for writing the records to the file.

```
        this.path_to_file =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportDir"] +
DateTime.Now.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
["Export_FileName"]) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
["Export_Extension"];


        FileStream fm = new FileStream
           (this.path_to_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.ReadWrite);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fm, Encoding.Default);

        List<Export> exportRecords = null;

        exportRecords = ExportList();
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
           foreach (Export ex in exportRecords)
           {
               sw.Write(ex.ExportLine());
              sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
              sw.Flush();
              exportlines += ex.ExportLine() + "\n";
               i++;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
           Log.Write(exc.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why is this line in your code?

```
      exportlines += ex.ExportLine() + "\n"
```

Assuming it is a string variable it grows and grows and grows... and consumes memory.

Comment: Perhaps you should also suggest a solution, such as StringBuilder.

Comment: If it isn't used for anything else not shown in the OP the implied solution is to take it out.

Comment: Mmm, im trying it without that extra line now, maybe that would help :)

Comment: pfff, and THAT was the solution ... THK U

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading records from the database?  If you're using a RecordSet you could process each record individually instead of bringing them all into memory (ExportList()).

Answer (score 0):

When growing the `exportlines` (I assume it is a string), it doubles the amount of memory taken (original + new value with apppended value). A StringBuilder will suffer from the same problem, only not on every string added, just when the buffer is full.

If you want a record of the strings written to the stream, you could create a List and add every line to the list. So you are not doubling (at least), the needed storage.

But if the amount of strings is that high, what extra information could you possibly get from it? It is just too much.

Also, why do you flush the stream every time?

Comment: No, it does not. You should close it in the end rather than flush it after every line.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the string growth discussed above, instead of ExportList() returning a List(Of Export) you could make it return IEnumerable(Of Export) and do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Export> ExportList() {
    foreach (Export ex in whateveryouaredoing) {
        yield return ex;
    }
}
```

The key line being "yield return ex". I assume you are looping through some other collection and filling a List with those Export objects then returning the entire list. In many cases you can limit your memory consumption to that of a single record at a time by using the yield return approach which turns your ExportList method into an iterator. It will basically run the body of your loop every time the yield is encountered, thus requiring only a single Export object to be in use at a time.